# MarkLogic - Slow Fsync Notice/warning in errorlog file continuously

Tags: performance, warnings, marklogic

We are using ML instance on AWS. We are using magnetic disks to store data. 
We are experiencing a lot of slow fsync messages in our log files

```
2019-07-10 00:00:01.756 Info: Memory 46% phys=31816 virt=51033(160%) rss=14950(46%) anon=13748(43%) file=2903(9%) forest=7442(23%) cache=10240(32%) registry=1(0%)
2019-07-10 00:00:02.036 Notice: Slow fsync /data/failover/Forests/test-003-1-1/Journals/Journal-20190709-235839-8921048-15627167181139510-10676271677428093868-9000702, 562.1 KB in 1.637 sec
2019-07-10 00:00:02.042 Notice: Slow fsync /data/Forests/test-modules/Label, 1.316 sec
2019-07-10 00:00:02.043 Notice: Slow fsync /data/Forests/Schemas/Label, 1.305 sec
2019-07-10 00:00:02.043 Notice: Slow fsync /data/Forests/Security/Label, 1.312 sec
2019-07-10 00:00:02.195 Notice: Slow fsync /data/Logs, 1.22 sec
2019-07-10 00:00:13.836 Warning: Slow fsync /data/failover/Forests/test-003-1-1/Label, 2.445 sec
2019-07-10 00:00:13.886 Warning: Slow msync /data/Forests/test-001-1/0000844d/Ordinals, 1 MB in 2.007 sec
2019-07-10 00:00:13.888 Notice: Slow fsync /data/failover/Forests/test-002-1-1/Label, 1.995 sec
2019-07-10 00:00:14.139 Info: Merged 444 MB in 94 sec at 5 MB/sec to /data/Forests/test-001-1/0000844b
2019-07-10 00:00:14.995 Info: Merging 690 MB from /data/Forests/test-001-1/0000844b, /data/Forests/test-001-1/00008449, /data/Forests/test-001-1/0000844a, and /data/Forests/test-001-1/0000844c to /data/Forests/test-001-1/0000844e, timestamp=15627162115706539
2019-07-10 00:00:42.740 Info: Saved 84 MB in 24 sec at 4 MB/sec to /data/failover/Forests/test-002-1-1/000041b5
2019-07-10 00:00:45.861 Info: Merged 193 MB in 58 sec at 3 MB/sec to /data/failover/Forests/test-002-1-1/000041b6
```

What is the reason for getting the above "slow fsync" messages. Does it means that the Disks are slow or there is Network congestion. How to find out the cause of these messages.

Also does it implies that query execution will also be working slowly? or any other impact on MarkLogic performance?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This [knowledge base article](https://help.marklogic.com/Knowledgebase/Article/View/508/0/understanding-slow-infrastructure-notification) has a lot of great detail about these error messages.

In particular, an fsync should complete in milliseconds so seeing that its taking about 2.5 seconds to complete is very concerning:

```
2019-07-10 00:00:13.836 Warning: Slow fsync /data/failover/Forests/test-003-1-1/Label, 2.445 sec
```

The purpose of fsync is to "[synchronize a file's in-core state with storage device](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fdatasync.2.html)". A slow fsync essentially means your disk is running slowly. The impact of this is that reading or writing data directly on the disk can take longer. There can be a number of reasons why this may happen. Some things to check:

- Do you have a lot of master forests on that host due to failover? Correctly balancing the master forests across all hosts may help.
- Is there a correlation between slow fsync and running queries? Optimizing your queries to pull less documents off disk may help.
- Do you have software besides MarkLogic running on that host? (NodeJS app, Splunk, etc.) Letting MarkLogic run exclusively on that host may help.

It's generally a good idea to work this through with MarkLogic Support or your friendly neighborhood consultant if you can't quickly identify the cause.